# How to get a data from the row of the last parent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get a table looking like this:

[image]

If the id doesn't get a parent, I need to get "created_at" of it and if he got one, I need to get the "created_at" of the last parent. I tried left join, without success.

Expected results are:

- id 1 : 1/1/2000
- id 3 : 1/1/2000
- id 5 : 1/2/2000

Comment: Where is the column with 2/2/2020?

Comment: it was a typo. Edited.

Comment: What happened to the other two rows?  What is the logic for filtering?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree(id, created_at, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, created_at, parent_id
    FROM your_table
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        c.id, 
        p.created_at, 
        c.parent_id
    FROM tree AS p, your_table AS c 
    WHERE c.parent_id = p.id
)
SELECT * FROM tree AS n
```

Look up at this fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyqSDNapZBm6zd3eZ4wauo/1

Comment: Maybe yes, I need to try to incorporate it into a bigger query now

Comment: It doesn't work with id 5. It only check the parent once. But the parent of id 5 got a parent, so I need to check the parent of his parent.

Comment: I've changed the answer